# Python add string to a list loop

Tags: python, string, list, loops, python-3.x

I have a var `vk_read` from Python `HTMLParser` which handle data like this: `['id168233095']`

Now I'm trying to collect all data from this var 'vk_read' after script runs in a list. Should be like: `['id168233095', 'id1682334534', 'id16823453', 'etc...']`

```
if vk_read:
    vk_ids = []
    for line in vk_read:
        if vk_read != '':
            vk_ids.append(vk_read)
            print(vk_ids)
```

This is the result:

```
['id168233095']
['id168233095', 'id168233095']
['id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095']
['id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095']
['id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095']
['id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095', 'id168233095']
```

After some advice code has been changed (see at the end of this post)

```
if vk_read not in vk_ids:
    vk_ids.append(vk_read)
print(vk_ids)
```

But in this case result is:

```
['id45849605']
['id91877071']
['id17422363']
['id119899405']
['id65045632']
['id168233095']
```

That means my `vk_read` add itself up to 10 times and then my script starts to add the next one.

Also trying `list.insert()`- and have the same result. (!!!)

How can I run this loop to catch all different result in one list after script runs as many times as the data can be found from the parsed file.

**Nota bene:**
I've updated the code as advised for `list1.append(list0)` but in my case this method still return the same result as described above.
And changed list name to avoid further confusions.

**LAST UPDATE**
Thanks for helping, guys, you`re really push me in right way: [same on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663410/4915733)

> The problem appears to be that you are reinitializing the list to an empty list in each iteration:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import re, sys, random, csv

with open('test.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as content_file:
    read_data = content_file.read()

vk_ids = []

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        href = str(attrs)
        for line in href:
            id_tag = re.findall('/\S+$', href)
            id_raw = str(id_tag)

            if re.search('/\w+\'\)\]', id_raw):
                global vk_read
                vk_read = id_raw
            else:
                break
            for ch in ['/', ')', '[', ']', '"', "'"]:
                if ch in vk_read:

                    vk_read = vk_read.replace(ch, "")

            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328193/python-add-string-to-a-list-loop
            for vk_id in vk_read:
                if vk_id not in vk_ids:
                    vk_ids.append(vk_read)
                    break
            print(vk_ids)
            break
```

**N.B.**
After last changes

```
print(type(vk_ids))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: `for line in vk_read:`  Why aren't you using `line` inside your for-loop?

Comment: It's probably a good idea not to name a variable `list`, as it shadows an often used builtin.

Comment: `list.insert(0, vk_read)` is a very inefficient operation because each time you insert an item all the other items need to be shifted one location to the right.  This will become really slow if your list grows large.

Comment: @trianglesis is it your actual indentation? if so, everything after `id_tag= re.findall(...)` is wrong. I assume it should all be in the `for line in href` loop

Comment: @JulienSpronck I`ve made some changes already

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
vk_ids = []
if vk_read:
    for line in vk_read:
        vk_ids.append(format(line))
    print(vk_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you were not making use of the `line` variable inside the loop. At each iteration, you are inserting the entire `vk_read` variable.

Assuming that vk_read is a list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
lis = [line for line in vk_read if line != '']
print lis
```

If you need it reversed (as seems to be the case by your use of `insert`, just use `reversed`:

```
lis = list(reversed([line for line in vk_read if line != '']))
```

However, `vk_read` seems to be a string not a list.

Comment: His example code is actually equivalent to `lis = reversed([vk_read for line in vk_read if vk_read != ''])`.  The `if vkread != ''` can be skipped as the loop wouldn't happen if `vk_read` were equal to an empty string.  `reversed` is used because OP is using `list.insert(0, vk_read)`.  The most efficient equivalent would be `lis = len(vk_read) * [vk_read]` (`reversed` doesn't really matter because we're just inserting `vk_read`, not `vk_read`'s ordered contents.)

Comment: I just assumed that it was a mistake since line is not referenced inside the loop

Comment: While this may or may not be right, you should try to establish the problem the OP ran in to and why this can help solve the problem.

Comment: @FrankV let me know if my last edit is more helpful.

Comment: if vk_read:
                vk_ids = [line for line in vk_read if line != '']
                print(vk_ids)
And still have the same, but separately for every character: ['i', 'd', '1', '6', '8', '2', '3', '3', '0', '9', '5']

Comment: @trianglesis do this `print type(vk_read)`, is it a string or a list?

Comment: @trianglesis if you have one string with one id, i don't know what your expected output is, how do you want to make a list out of that?

Comment: @julien-spronck in my situation I try to collect all different variable data into one list. I want to collect all founded ids in one list and then manipulate with it

Comment: I understand that but where do the id's come from ... As far as I can see, you have ... `vk_read == 'id168233095'`. That is a string. If you iterate through the string (with a for loop), you will just iterate through all its characters. so, that's not working. Where are the other id's coming from? are you already inside another for loop and vk_read will change at each iteration?

Comment: @JulienSpronck yes, vk_read will change each time. This variable data catches from HtmlParser from open file.html where a lot of ids stored. I understand, that I'm doing it wrong while trying to add str to list but after two days of googling I'm totally confused. I see, that I should first convert string with list of characters to one object, I'm trying to split, but also get different results far from needed.

Comment: @trianglesis i posted another answer ... see below, let me know if it works better. If not, I suggest that you rephrase your question, clearly stating what variable you have and what their values are ... Your question is highly not clear.

Comment: @JulienSpronck unfortunately I can't run `print type(vk_read)` because Python 3.4 return `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @trianglesis well, yes, in python 3, just do `print(type(vk_read))`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are inside a loop, `vk_read` is a string that changes at each iteration:

```
vk_ids = [] ## initialize list outside the main loop

## main loop
for some_variable in some_kind_of_iterator: ## this is just a placeholder, i don't know what your loop looks like.

    ## get the value for vk_read
    vk_read = ...

    ## append to vk_ids
    if vk_read and vk_read not in vk_ids:
        vk_ids.append(vk_read)

print vk_ids
```

Comment: Trying different constructions and also trying to make readable code, but now I have: `vk_ids.append(vk_read)` is `<class 'list'>` but the list still does not collect different data from variable. Something I`ve lost.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I've doing it wrong and run iteration and list append all time wiping prev list.
[Here is comment about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663391/using-a-loop-to-add-objects-to-a-listpython)